# What is the best way to set the "cloud-provider" variable in KubeSpray Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, kubernetes

I am using the master branch of KubeSpray. I use Terraform to provision AWS resources using the scripts in `contrib/terraform/aws`. However, the aws_cloud_provider is not enabled by default.

The [cloud](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.13.2/docs/cloud.md) document says to use `cloud-provider=aws` in the ansible playbook command to run the `cluster.yaml` playbook is executed. However, I have also seen documentation that says `cloud-provider` should be set to `external`.

What is the best method to set `cloud-provider` given that the cluster will be run on AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two answers to this question.

**one** - add the `cloud-provider` option to your `ansible-playbook` command as shown below.

```
ansible-playbook \
  -vvvvv \
  -i ./inventory/hosts \
  ./cluster.yml \
  -e ansible_user=centos \
  -e cloud_provider=aws \
  -e bootstrap_os=centos \
  --become \
  --become-user=root \
  --flush-cache \
  -e ansible_ssh_private_key_file=$PKI_PRIVATE_PEM \
  | tee kubespray-cluster-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M").log
```

**two**

Uncomment the cloud_provider option in group_vars/all.yml and set it to 'aws'

**proof**

I've tried the first answer. The proof is that the AWS ELB moves out of the pending status.

```
$ kubectl -n ingress-nginx get svc
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                                     PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.57.196   aa....amazonaws.com   80:32111/TCP,443:31854/TCP   109s
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.233.11.133   <none>                                                                          443/TCP                      109s
```